# How to define how type appears on the Julia REPL

Tags: julia, read-eval-print-loop

I am not clear on how I should define the appearance of a type on the Julia REPL. There are a number of similar sounding functions, including: display, show, print, writemime etc.

Answer (score 8):

You need to overload Base.show() for the type.

```
julia> import Base: show

julia> type Foo
           x
           y
           z
       end

julia> Base.show(io::IO, f::Foo) = println(io, "Foo: x=$(f.x), y=$(f.y), z=$(f.z)")
show (generic function with 98 methods)

julia> Foo("Hello ", "World", "!")
Foo: x=Hello, y=World, z=!
```

Comment: Notice that if you overload the method this way: `Base.show`, then you don't even need to do `import Base: show`.

Comment: You also almost always want to specify concrete types for all the fields in the type:  `julia> type Foo x::Int64; y::Float64; z::UTF8String end`

Comment: Having done this my type displays correctly as the value in a dict. (I'm not bothering posting code because it relies on a SharedArray being hosted on a remote machine via SLURM). It doesn't work if I call "julia> x" directly.